# Named scope for counting children

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need a scope that counts the children and compares it to another number. Something like this:

Training_date.rb

```
scope :not_full, ->{where("subscriptions.count < candidate_limit")}
```

And then call that scope onto a training_date  index. Only i get an unknown column error.

Comment: Scope is added under these modal subscriptions or other one.

Comment: `scope :not_full, ->(candidate_limit) { where ["subscriptions.count < ?", candidate_limit] }` .Perhaps you would also need to join `subscriptions`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
scope :not_full, ->{ where("subscriptions.count < candidate_limit") }
```

That won't work unless you join `subscriptions` and if `count` is a column in `subscriptions`. But I think that the following is what you want:

```
scope :not_full, -> do
  where("
    training_dates.candidate_limit > (
      SELECT COUNT(*) FROM subscriptions WHERE (
        subscriptions.training_date_id = training_dates.id
      )
    )
  ")
end
```

With the right associations, the following should also work:

```
scope :not_full, -> do
  joins(:subscriptions).
  group("training_dates.id").
  having("training_dates.candidate_limit > COUNT(subscriptions.id)")
end
```

Comment: Sorry you are correct try this `joins(:subscriptions).having('count(subscriptions.id) < training_dates.candidate_limit').group('training_dates.id')`. Seems like what he is looking for and the query is `SELECT training_dates.* FROM training_dates INNER JOIN subscriptions ON subscriptions.training_date_id = training_date.id GROUP BY training_date.id HAVING count(subscriptions.id) < training_date.candidate_limit`. Again the assumption is `TrainingDate has_many :subscriptions`

Comment: It doesnt seem to work for newly added ones. It works like this. <% @training_dates.reverse.each do |t| %>
     <% if t.candidate_limit != Subscription.group(:training_date_id).count[t.id] %>

Answer (score 0):

```
scope :not_full, { :include => :subscriptions, :conditions => 'subscriptions.count < candidate_limit' }
```