# Turn 'if' statement into a named scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope, named-scope

```
<% @training_dates.reverse.each do |t| %>
  <% if t.candidate_limit != Subscription.group(:training_date_id).count[t.id] %>
      <%= t.name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I want to turn this `if` statement into a scope so I can do `@training_dates.(scope).reverse.each`.

Comment: I think you need add some details about `@traqining_dates` variable, `Subscription` Model, and The scope add for Model not for Variable as: `Subscription.training_date_count` to return count of trainging_date

Comment: Why not use the scopes we helped you define in [Your Previous Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27620689/named-scope-for-counting-children). This would be the equivalent. so `@training_dates = TrainingDate.not_full.reverse` then `@training_dates.each do |t|`. I am not sure what your comment on that post means when you say "doesn't work for new ones". It works based on when the call is made so obviously if someone signs up after the call there is not much you can do other than notify the user that the TrainingDate is now full.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your other models are, but the sample scope for `training_date` model should like follows (for `rails` 4):

```
class TrainingDate
   scope :sss, -> do
      where.not(candidate_limit: Subscription.group(:training_date_id).count(:id))
           .order(:desc)
   end
end
```

and then:

```
sss.each { |t| t.name }
```

For other `rails` versions you have to user [arel](/questions/tagged/arel) gem.